# Converting columns of a dataframe to factor

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 100 columns and I want to convert them all into factor. Let's assume the data frame,

```
a <- as.integer(c(1,2,1,2,1,1))
b <- as.integer(c(1,2,3,3,3,1))
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I am trying this,

```
library(dplyr)
colwise(df, as.factor(df))
```

which give me an error like this,

```
> colwise(df, as.factor(df))
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Any suggestion how to do this correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df[] <- lapply(df, factor)`.

Comment: `apply(df, 2, as.factor`)

Comment: Thanks, @RuiBarradas it works. I tried lapply, but missing [] this part.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, we use `factor` within `mutate_all` for converting all columns to `factor`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_all(factor)
```